# Creating image renditions using docPrint

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

I am trying to create multiple images of different resolution using DocPrint, in which I am facing problem with paper size of image. Below is the Image having resolution of 642x480 created using Docprit, ***if you right click the image and click on View Image/Open image in new tab*** you will see there are two white lines at the right and bottom of image .[image] 
the parameters which I am passing to DocPrint are:

```
string strAllOptions = "-* \"VL6IEN2GRW8EYN8P1D7F\"";
strAllOptions +=" -e -w 642 -h 480 -f 6.69x5 in";
docPrintObj.docPrintCOM_DocumentConverterEx(UserName, Password, SourcefilePath, OutputFilePath, strAllOptions);
```

***where w = width in pixels, h = height pixels and f = paper size in inches***

> formula to get paper size (pixels * 0.01041667)

I tried giving different width and height while maintaining the Aspect ratio of image but was having the same problem every time.

Any type of help would be appreciated.

*Note: I have to use DocPrint for creating image renditions.*